# Heroku launch application error Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Trying to launch an app on Heroku, but it keeps getting an application error.  Here are the heroku logs, Please let me know what I can do to get it the application running.  We have implemented pusher and can get the website to work on local host (even the pusher features across different localhost machines) but other than that it does not work on heroku.

```
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:2:in `<class:CommentsController>': undefined method `post' for CommentsController:Class (NoMethodError)
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `require'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-11-04T19:57:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:46992
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:2:in `<class:CommentsController>': undefined method `post' for CommentsController:Class (NoMethodError)
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `require'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-11-04T19:57:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-11-04T19:57:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-11-04T19:57:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-11-04T19:57:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-11-04T20:07:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2012-11-04T20:07:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2012-11-04T20:07:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-11-04T20:17:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2012-11-04T20:17:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2012-11-04T20:17:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-11-04T20:22:51+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET followalong.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-11-04T20:22:52+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET followalong.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Something is trying to `POST` to `/comments` and you haven’t defined a `create` method on the `CommentsController`. What if you implement that method?

Comment: Which steps have you done using the Heroku Toolbox leading up to this point?

Comment: This isn't an incoming request -- it's a problem loading the `CommentsController` class. (I think line 2 includes a call to `post` -- maybe it's a misplaced route definition?) What is the contents of `app/controllers/comments_controller.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you are not getting this error while working normally on your local host. Try to remove or comment the CommentsController call and check whether you are able to deploy the application on Heroku? And once you make the application run, then you can enable and check  what is really making the cause for this error.